# How do we partially update a state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I was wondering what is the best way to partially update a state of a component in React/React-Native. Other than the fact that I can make a function which takes the current state and creates a new state and merges the new {key:value} and the previous state. For example:

```
{
      dataStream:[//having data here], 
      formData: {
         'first_name': 'Richard',
         'last_name' : 'Barbieri',
      } 
}
```

I want to update last_name to another value. When I call
`this.setState(formData:{{'last_name':newValue}})`, it resets the formData dictionary to just last name: new Value. Is there a way to this efficiently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there are two things you could try:

1. Spread operator

liks so

```
this.setState({
    formData: {
        ...this.state.formData, 
        "last_name" : newValue 
    } 
});
```

or

2. Take current state's first_name and reapply it:

like so

```
this.setState({ 
    formData: { 
        "first_name": this.state.formData.first_name, 
        "last_name" : newValue 
    } 
})
```

I'm not too sure about the first one, but I think the second one should work.

Comment: Spread operator should go first. Your code will overwrite the `newValue` with the original.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, I had done the second solution and it works. Just was not sure if this was the way to go. But yes this works as well!

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @DebojitKaushik Might want to keep in mind the first one as, if you were to have more variables inside formData that you wanted to keep, the first is going to be much simpler in keeping all the variables rather than having to write each one out.

Comment: Why are you unsure of the first one? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

What happens is normal because you reassign the whole forData.

If you want to add something to the existing form data do something like that (there are plenty of other solutions ^^)

```
this.setState({
    formData: Object.assign(this.state.formData, { 'last_name': newValue } 
})
```